# Google API sign in listener run multiple times

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-calendar-api

I am developing a simple vue module to add events to google calendar. Once user signs in I am having a listener and I will call a method to add an event to the calendar.  To get the gapi, I am using this vue library. https://github.com/cedpoilly/vue-gapi. But once I add the event and try to add another event, the addEvent method will run multiple times. For example if I add the event once all looks good. But If I press it again It will open the google calendar two times and add the same event two times. https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-chaum-dg7nf

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 ml-5 mt-3">
      <b-form>
        <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label="Add to" label-for="input-2">
          <b-button variant="outline-primary" @click="handleAuthClick">
            <b-icon icon="calendar3" aria-hidden="true"></b-icon> Google Calendar
          </b-button>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-form>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
     
      data(){
        return {
          show: true,
          disabled: false,
          items: '',
          event: '',
          gapi: null,
          partnerEmail: '',
          listner: null,
        }
      }
        methods: {
          onSubmit(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            //alert(JSON.stringify(this.form));
            //this.meetingEdit(this.form);
            this.$router.push({ path: '/portal/meetingEdit/' })
          },
          deleteMeeting() {
            this.$router.push({ path: '/portal/meetingDelete/' })
          },
          addEvent() {

            var startDate = new Date(this.form.MeetingTime);
            var msDuration = (Number(this.form.Duration.split(':')[0]) * 60 * 60 + Number(this.form.Duration.split(':')[1]) * 60 + Number(this.form.Duration.split(':')[2])) * 1000;
            var endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + msDuration);
            var isoStartDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000).toISOString().split(".")[0];
            var isoEndDate = new Date(endDate.getTime() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000).toISOString().split(".")[0];
            var InviteesArr = [];
            var tempArr = this.form.Invitees.trim().split(',');
            for (var email of tempArr) {
              if (email !== "") {
                var obg = { 'email': email };
                InviteesArr.push(obg);
              }
            }

            var partner = { 'email': this.partnerEmail };
            InviteesArr.push(partner);

            this.event = {
              'summary': this.form.Topic,
              'location': this.form.InviteLink,
              'description': this.form.inviteDes,
              'start': {
                'dateTime': isoStartDate,
                'timeZone': this.form.Timezone
              },
              'end': {
                'dateTime': isoEndDate,
                'timeZone': this.form.Timezone
              },
              'attendees': InviteesArr,
              'conferenceData': null,
            }

            this.$getGapiClient().then((gapi) => {
              // gapi.sheets.spreadsheet.get(...)
              var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                'calendarId': 'primary',
                'conferenceDataVersion': 1,
                'resource': this.event
              });

              request.execute( (event)=> {
                console.log(event);
                window.open(event.htmlLink, '_blank');
              });

              this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
              this.gapi = null;
            })
          },
          updateSigninStatus(bool) {
            if (bool) {
              console.log('login D');
              this.addEvent();
            } else {
              console.log('not login');
            }
          },
          handleAuthClick() {
            this.$getGapiClient().then((gapi) => {
              this.gapi = gapi;
              this.listner = this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus);
              this.updateSigninStatus(this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());

              if (this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()) {
                this.addEvent();
              } else {
                this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
              }

            })
          }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

But I click the button  addEvent() method will run more than once.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `handleAuthClick()` you call `updateSigninStatus` that contains a call to `addEvent()`, but inside `handleAuthClick()` you also call `addEvent()`!

Call it only in one of the functions and that should solve you problem.

UPDATE

The code you linked to in the code sandbox contians unlike the code in your question the line

`recurrence: ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"]`.

This means that you set up a recurrence, or in other words request for the event to be repeated after of day.

Remove this line if this is not what you intend.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried it. But still I have the problem.

Comment: I had a look at the link to the code sandbox - it contians the line `recurrence: ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"]` which creates a recurrent event that is repeated after 1 day.